# How do I pass build-time config to heroku container build scripts?

Tags: docker, heroku

I have a `Dockerfile`, thusly:

```
# Use a multi-stage build to handle the compiling, installing, etc.

# STAGE 1: Install node_modules on a stretch container
FROM node:10-stretch as base
ARG APP_DIR=/node
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
RUN chown node:node $APP_DIR
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
USER node
RUN ["npm", "install", "--no-optional"]
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# STAGE 2: Extend the base image as a builder image
FROM base as builder
ARG APP_NAME
ARG BASE_URL
ARG NODE_ENV
RUN npm run build -- --mode=production && rm -rf node_modules && npm install --no-optional --production

# STAGE 3: Copy the 'build' directory from previous stage and run in alpine
# Since this does not extend the base image, we need to set workdir, user, etc. again.
FROM node:10-alpine
ARG APP_DIR=/node
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node $APP_DIR/dist .
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node $APP_DIR/node_modules ./node_modules
USER node
CMD ["node", "./server"]
```

and what I'd like to do is have thos environment variables in stage 2 set by Heroku on build. If I set those values in the Dockerfile, they do end up being available in the build - but otherwise they don't seem to get passed the values from `heroku.yml`.

According to [this documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#setting-build-time-environment-variables) I should be able to set these values in `heroku.yml`, but thus far - I've been unsuccessful. My `heroku.yml` file looks like this:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    APP_NAME: My App
    BASE_URL: /
    NODE_ENV: production
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's necessary to repeat the `ARG` statements like this in order to have them accessible to each build stage:

```
# All `ARG`s must be referenced appear *before* the first `FROM`
ARG APP_NAME
ARG BASE_URL
ARG NODE_ENV

# STAGE 1: Install node_modules on a stretch container
FROM node:10-stretch as base
# Any subset of the `ARG`s can then be imported into the build stage
ARG APP_DIR

# STAGE 2: Extend the base image as a builder image
FROM base as builder
# Any subset of the `ARG`s can then be imported into the build stage
ARG APP_NAME
ARG BASE_URL
ARG NODE_ENV


# STAGE 3: Copy the 'build' directory from previous stage and run in alpine
FROM node:10-alpine
# Any subset of the `ARG`s can then be imported into the build stage
ARG APP_DIR
```

> **NOTE** If you overwrite the values in any state, e.g. `ARG APP_NAME=/node`, this value will supersede the values you're obtaining from the environment (from the `heroku.yml`)

Comment: Right, the thing is though - I don't need them at any other time than Stage2. It's just used to compile the application name into the index.html file. I don't need them at runtime. The issue here seems to be the values set in heroku.yml not being passed to the docker build container

Comment: You need only use `ARG`s at the top and in Stage2. You can also add a step in the Dockerfile e.g. `RUN echo ${APP_NAME}` to show the value at build time.

Comment: Why do I need them at the top? The only place I need them is at build time which is when the compiler runs. After that I don't care about them.

Comment: It gives you the possibility to define (global) default values for the variables to save repeatedly setting defaults after each FROM. I consider it a useful documentation (!) step too to aid clarity. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Comment: Sure, though - that doesn't really address the problem at hand which is that variables aren't being passed to the container in the first place.

Comment: You're correct; it doesn't. When I responded, I thought that the `ARG`s prefix was a requirement with multi-stage builds but reading up on it to help answer your question, I learned that it is not. As long as the `ARG` values are populated by e.g. `docker build --build-arg=APP_NAME=... ...`, the issue is with Heroku. I'm unfamiliar with Heroku but, I see no obvious problem with your Heroku spec. Hopefully someone who is familiar with Heroku can point out the problem.